# Changed wordpress_http.conf for SSL, nginx won't start now

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vps

I'm using Vultr VPS and I followed this tutorial -https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-one-click-wordpress-app

Everything seemed to install correctly and I changed both (http & https) config files from:

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name_;
    #server_name wordpress.example.com;
```

to

```
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    #server_name wordpress.example.com;
```

and finally adding this to http

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Whenever I try to restart nginx I get this error stating that the authentication for root is incorrect? I wasn't prompted for a password and I am already logged in as root.

```
> -- Unit nginx.service has failed.
> -- 
> -- The result is RESULT. Nov 08 16:14:48 Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0
> tty=ssh ruser= rhost=2 Nov 08 16:14:51 Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]:
> Failed password for root from 218.92.0.203 port 57531 ssh2 Nov 08
> 16:14:53 Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: Failed password for root from
> 218.92.0.203 port 57531 ssh2 Nov 08 16:14:56 Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.203 port 57531
> ssh2 Nov 08 16:14:56 Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: Received disconnect
> from 218.92.0.203 port 57531:11:  [preauth] Nov 08 16:14:56
> Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: Disconnected from authenticating user
> root 218.92.0.203 port 57531 [preauth] Nov 08 16:14:56
> Above-Media-Team sshd[10921]: PAM 2 more authentication failures;
> logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.2 Nov 08 16:15:03
> Above-Media-Team sshd[10936]: Invalid user yp from 103.10.30.204 port
> 50794 Nov 08 16:15:03 Above-Media-Team sshd[10936]:
> pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown Nov 08 16:15:03
> Above-Media-Team sshd[10936]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication
> failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=1
```

I can't seem to figure this out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running nginx as a service (upstart?). And it looks like this service is initially running as an unprivileged user, yp. It's trying to raise its privileges, but it can't because the password is not set properly.

I can't tell you specifically what's wrong without seeing the full config for your service, but I would look in the configuration for anything that sets the username to be something other than root.